# jquery: array was filled, but became empty after exiting $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, foreach

So I have an array, say `arr = []`, defined. Then I use 
`$.each(otherArr, function(i, val))` to fill arr. Inside `$.each`, the array arr gets filled one by one. However, after I exit $.each, arr becomes empty. Not sure why. Here is the code:

```
var arr = [];
var url = "http://some_url/";
$.each(otherArr, function(idx, val){
     $.getJSON( url + val).then(function (result) {
         arr.push(agt);   
         console.log(arr); // -> this looks fine.
     });
});
console.log(arr); // -->> ughh.. it's empty.
```

Any idea why and how to fix this?

Comment: here you need to use callbacks...

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call